# Custom allocators - versus std::vector, and strange test results

Tags: c++

I followed a tutorial [here](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/au-memorymanager/) to make a custom memory manager for a simple class. Sure enough, as the page suggests, I had a dramatic increase in performance carrying out the tests. Here is the test code copied over:

```
Complex* array[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        array[j] = new Complex(i,j);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        delete array[j];
    }
}
```

Where `Complex` is a fairly straightforward class:

```
Class Complex {
public:
    Complex(double a, double b) :
        r(a),
        c(b)
    {}
private:
    double r;
    double c;
}
```

Before implementation of the manager, this test took an average of 3.30866 seconds to run on my machine.
After implementation of the manager (following the tutorial pretty much word-for-word - should I copy and paste all the code here?) the test took an average of 0.02842002 seconds.

This seemed like a great improvement, but I wanted to see how it fared against populating a std::vector, as this is the main container used in my existing code. The results were somewhat surprising:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    std::vector<Complex> values;
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        values.push_back(Complex(i, j));
    }
    values.clear();
}
```

This took an average of 0.0434723 seconds to run, with very similar results using overloaded new/delete and with default. Still twice as slow as using the custom manager, but here's where my faith in my own testing breaks down. I tried re-running the original test code without using the custom manager, and it took an average of 0.3028371 seconds.

While there is still an order of magnitude increase in performance, I instinctively feel suspicious of the whole test now. I have no idea where the sudden increase in performance in the original test came from. Is this a symptom of compiler optimizations? I'm using MSVC v142 toolset on Visual Studio 2019.

I've seen similar effects to this running production code multiple times, where the first run is slow and successive runs are faster. However, this effect did not occur when carrying out the very first original test - individual results were all grouped around the 3.3 second mark.

Could anyone shed any light on what is going on here? Is it worth writing custom allocators if the STL containers seem to perform so well? How can I improve my testing technique?

Comment: That's because `std::vector<Complex>` contains `Complex` objects, not pointers to dynamically allocated objects. You removed almost all of your `new`/`delete` pairs (and could remove even more by calling `values.reserve(5000);`).

Comment: I see. So my `std::vector<Complex>` contains these objects, and these are allocated from the heap when using the default allocator. My existing code involves handling of large `std::vector`s of `Complex`-like objects - am I out of luck if I hope to improve performance by using a custom allocator for this class?

Comment: While you are populating `vector` with your custom `Complex` objects, you are calling your `Complex` constructor every time. And when you are using `vector.push_back` instead of `vector.emplace_back` you create a copy of your custom object and then copy to your vector. Of course this will be much slower. Your tests aren't  very truthful.

Comment: "the first run is slow and successive runs are faster" There are several possible reasons for that, which include caches that are already populated and CPU clock throttling when load is low. You want to discard the first few measurements.

Comment: When we talk about allocator, we usually talk about heap-management class used by standard library (not STL, it's NOT STL!) You have memory manager for that particular class,  each container may have own manager. Using emplace_back or using  copy elision may alter results.

Comment: @Cactus'as I tried both `push_back` and `emplace_back` just now. The numbers coming out were almost identical, this is probably due the class simplicity. Point taken, though.

Comment: Don't forget about the "as if" rule and compiler optimizations. The aforementioned difference between `push_back` and `emplace_back` may disappear after code optimization.

Comment: 5k iterations of 1k items vs 5k ierations of 5k items hardly seems an equitable comparison regardless.

Comment: For me use  of custom `Complex` class instead using standard `std::complex<double >` is a clue that I should have limited trust to author of that article. And this use of `union` in `Listing 5` disqualifies author. Disclaimer: I didn't read this article just quickly review it to see if author is trustworthy. IMO he is not.

Comment: Just realised I made a typo in the test with std::vector... it was pushing 1000 items, not 5000.

Comment: @MarekR At least he numbered the listings so we can criticize them ....